# Vector of class object with a pointer data member

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Let's say I have a class just like this:

```
class example{
    double * ptr;

    public:
        example();
        ~example();
};
```

with methods implemented:

```
example::example(){
    ptr = new double;
    *ptr = 0;
}
example::~example(){delete ptr;}
```

If, in main, I create a `std::vector<example> v;` and `v.push_back(example());`, I just get a segmentation fault due invalid deletes. I'm not really sure what's causing this and if there's a  way to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write copy/move constructors for raw pointers, default constructor just copies ptr by address. Thus, you have the same ptr value in example() temporary object and in the `example` inside vector.
destructor is called for temporary `example` object, deletes ptr. Then `example` destructor is called from vector, it tries to delete ptr, which was already deleted by previous destructor call.